# What role does the context in EF?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, repository-pattern

What role does the context in EF? Do I have to use the repository pattern?
Because in my understanding of the context it is already repository.
This is an abstraction of the store or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is heavily debated so consider the following as "an answer".

The context in EF is a Unit of Work, where the DbSets are the repositories. Together they form an abstraction over a database. The SaveChanges method will commit all changes made to each repository.

There are a lot of examples where people use the repository pattern to create an IRepository that uses a context/DbSet internally. But by doing this you are:

- creating an abstraction over an abstraction
- losing functionality of EF since your interface hides the implementation

The reason you would create this additional abstraction is that you can swap out EF for something else, say another database/storage. 
But I believe [yagni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) is in place here. If you are starting a project that targets a SQL database, what are the odds that your customer will change to Oracle for example?

Hope this helps.

Comment: My opinion is the same as yours. And I think that the repository will make abstration over the EF itself?